# Interpreting a categorical feature's overall significance

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data

There are several discussions with similar headings, e.g. 
[overall effects of categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73767/overall-effects-of-categorical-variables) or 
[Overall Significance vs. Individual Variable Significance in Mutliple Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109048/overall-significance-vs-individual-variable-significance-in-mutliple-regression) or
[Categorical Significance Test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344267/categorical-significance-test)

...none of which fully answer me, and with subtly conflicting answers, I think.

Question: Once I've run a multiple regression which includes a categorical variable (5 levels in my case), what is the right test to see whether the variable, not the levels, is statistically significant to the model?

Below a screenshot of my regression (fit in python using statsmodels, and it's the AG Rating fella I'd like to check out).

[image]

Update: This may well be a duplicate. I ask this is the context of OLS (not logistic regression, the topic of the questions linked) and, python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Significance of categorical predictor in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60817/significance-of-categorical-predictor-in-logistic-regression)

Comment: Is AG rating always present? Your AG_Rating seems to be an ordinal variable. You can try to model it as a continuous variable and look at the confidence interval for the resulting coefficent. That makes it easier to interpret. You can also do an extra sum of squares F test comparing your current model and one excluding all of the AG_Rating variables.

Comment: Fit the model once without and once with the categorical predictor and perform an likelihood-ratio test. I found an example with Python and `statsmodels` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803236/likelihood-ratio-test-statsmodels).

Comment: Also relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr

Answer (score 1):

I would do hierarchical regression analysis, creating let's say 2 models, one without this categorical variable, and another with it. Then run anova to see whether adding this variable significantly improved the model. I did it in R, and can't tell how to do it with Python.